# Install SMTP service in VISTA

Tags: windows-vista, smtp

I want to install SMTP Service in my system, But not able to figure out where the option is there to add it.

I searched the web and what I found is to open "Turn Windows Features on or off", then click on "Install SMTP service".

I have Windows Vista on my system

But I couldn't find it.

Can any one help me out about how to install SMTP service in Windows Vista

Comment: thanks, i am new to stackoverflow..didnt know of this community

Answer (score 1):

The SMTP server, although previously included in IIS, wasn't supported by the IIS team. For whatever reason, the Microsoft owning team has decided to withdraw it from Vista, only including it with Server 2008.

Therefore you need a third party product. A good and simple replacement is [Free SMTP Server](http://www.softstack.com/freesmtp.html):

> Free SMTP Server is a SMTP server
>   program for Windows that lets you send
>   email messages directly from your
>   computer. It's very simple but very
>   useful for laptop users traveling
>   around the world and connecting their
>   PCs to different Internet Service
>   Providers in different countries. You
>   can use it instead of ISP's SMTP
>   server to increase your security and
>   privacy. Free SMTP Server supports all
>   email programs like Outlook Express
>   and Eudora, but best optimized to work
>   with Outlook Express. The email
>   program you already use for sending
>   and receiving messages can be
>   connected to the server in a very easy
>   way - by using the word "localhost"
>   instead of your current SMTP host.
>   Having done so, you can send messages
>   in a usual manner. Free SMTP Server is
>   very fast, while sending, it
>   establishes dozens of SMTP
>   connections, and gets the most out of
>   your Internet connection. The user
>   interface of the program is very easy
>   to learn, excellent documentation is
>   included. The program is freeware so
>   there is no reason not to download and
>   try it!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a simple answer to this.

- You can either download a third party SMTP service
- if you have an ISP supplies SMTP service, you can connect to that
- if you have an XP machine available, you can install IIS integrated SMTP service and connect to that

[SMTP service for IIS on Vista is not included.](http://weblogs.asp.net/steveschofield/archive/2006/12/19/iis7-post-23-vista-and-smtp-server-where-is-it.aspx)